# Diagram's Arrows

Tags: graphics, luatex, diagrams, arrows

I have a question for you.
I have some images in my latex file and I would like to connect some of them with arrows.
For example something like this:

Image1 --------> Image2

Image3 --------> Image4
       --------> Image5

(In the second example I have an image connected with 2 different images: images3 with images4 and images5 separately)
Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,join},
    every join/.style={-latex},node distance=2em]
 \node{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two graphics.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,join},
    every join/.style={-latex},node distance=2em]
 \node{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
 \node{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three graphics.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a different layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=2em]
 \node(a){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node[right=of a](b){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
 \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two graphics.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=2em]
 \node(a){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
 \matrix[right=of a,row sep=2em] {
 \node(b){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};\\
 \node(c){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};\\
 };
 \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
 \draw[->] (a) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three graphics.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, but in the second figure what I really would like to do is connect the first image to the second and the third, not in chain like you did, so there is "A" connected to "B" and "A" conntected to the duck

Comment: @Simo I am confused. Your question has `Image3 --------> Image4 --------> Image5`, and this is what the answer does. Please edit the question to show clearly what you want.

Comment: In the parenthesis in the original post I tried to explain it, but I will try again better.
I want that in the second example from figure A starts 2 arrows: one that goes to figure B and the other that goes to the last one

Comment: @Simo That's all easy to do if it is clear how B and C are arranged relative to each other, and relative to A. Should B and C be on top of each other, and A left of them? Or B and C side by side, and A above them?

Comment: Yes, B and C on top of each other and A on the left.

Comment: @Simo Added a proposal.

Comment: Another question, if all these figures are in a subfigures template there could be something to change?

Comment: @Simo Yes. But it is very hard for others to make concrete suggestions because you do not show a code that has these subfigures, say. You can add the arrows with `remember picture,overlay`, for instance.

Comment: Could you please give me an example using a subfigure template where, for istance, we have more figures like the second in the second example?

Comment: @Simo For instance, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385247) achieves this.

Comment: Sorry but I meant a subfigures template in which we use the arrows like in the example you gave to me

Comment: @simo Please ask a separate question on this in which you show the code without the arrows such that there are no misunderstandings.