# Subfigure with diagram's arrows

Tags: luatex, arrows, subfig

I need to implement some diagrams arrows, like the ones used with the `tikz` package in a `subfigure` template (I used `subfigure` because `subfloats` give me problems).

So the `subfigure` template is like the one in this older post [subfigure template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525478/side-caption-on-subfigure) and the arrows that I would like to insert are just the ones in this other post [arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527216/diagrams-arrows/527254?noredirect=1#comment1334806_527254).

Assuming I would like that for each couple of subfigures there's an arrow in between that link each caption.

EDIT:
This is a sample of the code, I do not include the begin document because I had multiple tex files.
So where I insert the $\longrightarrow$, instead, I would like an arrow like the one in the post I cited before.

```
...
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Mela Golden Delicious}]{
        \label{fig:mela1}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Lime}]{
        \label{fig:lime}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Mango}]{
        \label{fig:mango}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    $\longrightarrow$
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Mela Granny Smith}]{
        \label{fig:mela2}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Mandarino}]{
        \label{fig:manda}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Pompelmo}]{
        \label{fig:pom}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    $\longrightarrow$
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Arancia}]{
        \label{fig:aranc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Succo all'arancia}]{
        \label{fig:succo1}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    $\longrightarrow$
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Succo al pompelmo}]{
        \label{fig:succo2}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Cetriolo}]{
        \label{fig:cet}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    $\longrightarrow$
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Zucchina}]{
        \label{fig:zuc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
\end{center}
\caption{Example}
\label{fig:subfigures6}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You mean that you want an automated approach that draws an arrow between each caption of subfigures inside the same figure environment, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily automated, I just know the approach used in this post [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527216/diagrams-arrows/527254?noredirect=1#comment1334806_527254), but if there is an easier solution it is welcome.

Comment: Could you then please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your question that shows what exactly your current usage looks like and probably what you've tried to get your arrows?

Comment: I have inserted in the post a minimal code example

Comment: Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: What is wrong with the `$\longrightarrow$`s? You could include a free-hand sketch of what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you see the post I linked in the original post named "arrows" there is an example of what I would like to achieve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104408/discussion-between-simo-and-skillmon-likes-topanswers-xyz).

Comment: Just as a note, don't use the `center` environment inside of a `figure`, instead you should use `\centering`, `center` adds unwanted vertical space.

Comment: Please also note that `\footnotesize` doesn't take an argument, but acts as a switch, affecting everything from that point on wards in the current group. So instead of `\footnotesize{foo}` you should use `{\footnotesize foo}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution which first places the `\subfloat` (using the `subfig` package, you really shouldn't use `subfigure` anymore) and places some marks using the `tikzmark` library. Afterwards it draws the arrows as an `overlay`ed `tikzpicture`. Everywhere we want to have some white spaces, which is later filled by the arrows, we have to manually introduce that space (using `\hspace{1cm}` in this example). Additionally I use `\adjustimage` and its `valign=c` option to easily place the `\tikzmark`s approximately on the vertical centre of the pictures.

Also I removed all the white space around the contents of your `\subfloat`s (by placing `%` at the end of the lines, which removes the space added by a new line in TeX), and spaced them out more evenly by placing a few `\hfil`s.

The `\footnotesize` isn't necessary for `subfig` as it by default sets the fontsize of the `subfloat` captions to `\footnotesize`.

To get the arrows at the correct position you have to compile at least twice.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \subfloat[Mela Golden Delicious]{%
        \label{fig:mela1}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subfloat[Lime]{%
        \label{fig:lime}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subfloat[Mango]{%
        \label{fig:mango}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
        \tikzmark{mangoR}%
    }\hfil\hspace{1cm}%
    \subfloat[Mela Granny Smith]{%
        \label{fig:mela2}%
        \tikzmark{melaL}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[Mandarino]{%
        \label{fig:manda}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subfloat[Pompelmo]{%
        \label{fig:pom}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
        \tikzmark{pompelmoR}%
    }\hfil\hspace{1cm}%
    \subfloat[Arancia]{%
        \label{fig:aranc}%
        \tikzmark{aranciaL}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[Succo all'arancia]{%
        \label{fig:succo1}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
        \tikzmark{succoarR}%
    }\hspace{1cm}%
    \subfloat[Succo al pompelmo]{%
        \label{fig:succo2}%
        \tikzmark{succopoL}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[Cetriolo]{%
        \label{fig:cet}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
        \tikzmark{cetrioloR}%
    }\hspace{1cm}%
    \subfloat[Zucchina]{%
        \label{fig:zuc}%
        \tikzmark{zuccinaL}%
        \adjustimage{width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image}%
    }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=latex]
    \foreach\x/\y in
      {mangoR/melaL, pompelmoR/aranciaL, succoarR/succopoL, cetrioloR/zuccinaL}
      \draw[->] (pic cs:\x) -- (pic cs:\y);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example}
\label{fig:subfloats6}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!